# Filter rows of dataframes stored in a list and create new list

Tags: r, list, dataframe, filtering

I have a list with 64 dataframes.
Dataframe 1 and Dataframe 5 have to have the same row names.
The same with 2 and 6, 3 and 7, and so on.
I'm being able to run a for loop and create a new list, but something is not working: I end up having an incorrect number of rows.

Here a simplified example to reproduce it:

```
# Create dataframes and store in list
dfA <- data.frame(v1=c(1:6), v2=c("x1","x2","x3","x4","x5","x6"))
dfB <- data.frame(v1=c(1:6), v2=c("x1","x2","x3","x4","x5","x6"))
dfC <- data.frame(v1=c(1:5), v2=c("x1","x2","x3","x4","x5"))
dfD <- data.frame(v1=c(1:4), v2=c("x1","x2","x3","x4"))
example_dataframes = list(dfA, dfB, dfC, dfD)

# These vectors give the order of the process
vectorA = c(1,2)
vectorB = c(3,4)

# Create new list and start for loop
filtered_dataframes = list()
for (i in vectorA) {
   for (j in vectorB) {
df1 = example_dataframes[[i]]
df2 = example_dataframes[[j]]
test = intersect(df1$v2, df2$v2)
filtered_dataframes[[i]] <- df1[which(df1$v2 %in% test),]
filtered_dataframes[[j]] <- df2[which(df2$v2 %in% test),]
 }
}
```

For this example, I expect to obtain:

```
sapply(filtered_dataframes, nrow)
> 5 4 5 4
```

Comment: I guess you only need a single for-cycle to traverse indices of vectorA and vectorB, instead of a two-layered recursive for-cycle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This modified version should work to get the results you need.

```
dfA <- data.frame(v1=c(1:6), v2=c("x1","x2","x3","x4","x5","x6"))
dfB <- data.frame(v1=c(1:6), v2=c("x1","x2","x3","x4","x5","x6"))
dfC <- data.frame(v1=c(1:5), v2=c("x1","x2","x3","x4","x5"))
dfD <- data.frame(v1=c(1:4), v2=c("x1","x2","x3","x4"))
example_dataframes = list(dfA, dfB, dfC, dfD)

# Put the comparison vectors into a list. Exampl: To compare dataframes 1 and 3, put in c(1,3)
vector.list <- list(c(1,3),c(2,4))

# Create new list and start for loop
filtered_dataframes = list()

# Loop through the list of vectors
for (i in vector.list) {
    # Get the first dataframe from the current vector being processed
    df1 = example_dataframes[[i[1]]]

    # Get the second dataframe from the current vector being processed
    df2 = example_dataframes[[i[2]]]

    # Get the intersection of the two dataframes
    test = intersect(df1$v2, df2$v2)

    # Add the first filtered dataframe to the list of filtered dataframes
    filtered_dataframes[[i[1]]] <- df1[which(df1$v2 %in% test),]

    # Add the second filtered dataframe to the list of filtered dataframes
    filtered_dataframes[[i[2]]] <- df2[which(df2$v2 %in% test),]
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not obtaining what I expected. In the new list, dfA and dfC should have nrow=5, and dfB and dfD should have nrow=4. I would like to keep them in the same order.

Comment: I have modified my answer to fix the issue you are seeing. When setting up the dataframes to compare in `vector.list` just assign the two dataframes indexes in the same vector IE `c(1,3)` will compare the dataframes at indexes 1 and 3 from the `example.dataframes` list. I have also modified it so the dataframes will stay in their original index position when they are output to the `filtered_dataframes` list.